# How to select multiple specific values from a column in dataframe for plotting

Tags: python, pandas, plot, label, seaborn

I have a DataFrame which contains a column with categorical data named "Label".
This is the output for the df.Label.value_counts() code.

```
    O              382963
    B-protein       30269
    I-protein       24848
    I-DNA           15774
    B-DNA            9533
    I-cell_type      8748
    I-cell_line      7387
    B-cell_type      6718
    B-cell_line      3830
    I-RNA            1530
    B-RNA             951
```

I want use countplot() from seaborn library to plot this values but I want to plot counts just for the B-label values not all values in the Label column.

I've tried this

```
   sns.countplot(x=df.Label, data=df[-(df.Label == 'I-Protein')])
```

and it works just for the I-Protein label. Then I've tried to subtract other specific values but it didn't work.
For example I've tried this:

```
   sns.countplot(x=df.Label, data=df[-(df.Label == 'I-Protein' or 'I-DNA'])
```

and it was a failure.

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Try the following: `sns.countplot(x=df.Label, data=df[((df.Label != 'I-Protein') & (df.Label != 'I-DNA'))]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a DataFrame just for plotting. This way you can test and debug the data before sending it to Seaborn:

```
df_plot = df[df['Label'].str.startswith('B-')]
sns.countplot(x='Label', data=df_plot)
```

[image]